# CSS Skew glitch on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, visual-glitch

please have a look here:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/52918/

```
body.loading-end #test::after {
            animation: skewAction 3s ease;
        }

@keyframes skewAction{
        0%{
            bottom: -100px;
            transform: skewY(0deg);
        }
        50%{
            bottom: -100px;
            transform: skewY(4deg);
        }
        100%{
            bottom: -200px;
            transform: skewY(0deg);
        }
}
```

In firefox, the skewY transoform animation is creating a glitch!! (Chrome/Safari is working fine)  How comes, am I missing something.  I tried the browser prefixes in the css but it didn't change anything.

Is there maybe another possibility to easily create this skew effect (svg?).

Example (grey bar):

[image]

Comment: I dont see no glitch

Comment: For me its working fine, https://caniuse.com/#search=skew also says it should work fine.

Comment: That's strange.  I always get it (see screenshot).  I'm on the latest firefox version.